# How to make product reviews go to the waiting list instead of the approved reviews list by default. Wordpress + Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use Wordpress with Woocommerce plugin, and now all product reviews go to "approved" section in Products -> Reviews.
I need to make it goes in waitlist by default instead.
Can't find solution, maybe i'm blind)
So how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have custom AJAX to add reviews. There is an option in the `wp_insert_comment()` data argument called comment_approved. By default it's `1`, so I just need to make it `0` to change a comment status.

There is the code:

single-product.js:
`https://ibb.co/4PrkzBg/`

woocommerce/ajax-functions.js:
`https://ibb.co/jhdrqfb/`
`https://ibb.co/VYQPQfT/`

Comment: It is best to put the code as text into the answer instead of linking to an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can find what you are looking for on this page:

Settings > Discussion : Comment must be manually approved

Woocommerce uses wordpress comments by default and these settings also apply to product reviews.

Comment: Thanks for anwser!

This option has already been enabled.
We have custom ajax adding reviews, so i found the solution.

It's an option in the `wp_insert_comment()` data argument, called `comment_approved`, by default it's `1`, so i just need to make it `0` change comment status.

Thanks again!)